# Is it possible to import Borderlands save data into the PC version?

Tags: borderlands

With the release of Borderlands 2 imminent, I would like to play it on my PC.  An issue occurs, however, as I played the original on Xbox and would like to import that save data into Borderlands 2 when it comes out.

Now, as good as this game is, I do not want to buy it again and play through it for a 6th time, just get my data over to my PC.

Is there a tool similar to the import tools for Mass Effect that I can use to bring my Xbox data over?

Comment: Can Borderlands 2 even import a Borderlands save?  It's different player characters this time around.

Comment: I remember reading something that you will be able to get bonuses for importing a B1 save.  Standby while I find something on it

Comment: Ok so its [not much of a reward](http://www.shacknews.com/article/74692/borderlands-save-file-unlocks-content-in-borderlands-2), but I'm still curious regardless.

Comment: Why always with the hats?

Comment: Since it doesn't have anything to do with your particular characters, I think any PC save game in the right slot would work.  I wouldn't be terribly surprised if an appropriately named, but empty text file would work.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the PC and Xbox saves are compatible; I have borderlands for both PC and Xbox and have never heard of cross-platform saving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[WillowTree#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/willowtree/) is able to convert Borderlands saves between PC, PS3 and Xbox 360 formats.